# Editing with PHP give syntax error

Tags: php

I am trying to get only access token by removing all extra code but it always give me syntax error of **''**

**Here is my code**

```
$top = $_GET["user"];

$line = '$top';
 $decoded = json_decode($line,true);

 $token2 = $decoded['access_token'];
```

**$top**

```
{"session_key":"5.uDUKhUqs4_N0Ow.1492573795.34-100007001746590","uid":100007001746590,"secret":"a01298dab24aa3c62adea05c6a79392e","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBAKXNrDxZB5Wx9vYY4HO8ux38JNIdTmYxwr15SFVuk0BOBeKQdS9C8BE4CzmIgxmghonZAjQmAl0E5pygW7s3eZCGEE4PxeXXO5kV5a2zt27LHo80YiekAZBzN3zHA9kuIiYNquvDLdgNaLlTtTObUZC1BrCKepc9NY7a3ieXaOSM0gsQePO9tf8nSykNahAZDZD","machine_id":"Y972WDldq3SeEw4bTWfnVj9Z","confirmed":true,"identifier":"9431448548"}
```

Comment: Your error is not `''` either you are using error reporting incorrectly or the error is else where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is here `$line = '$top'` Here you are using single quotes which defines the value of `$line` as `$top` **instead of**

```
{"session_key":"5.uDUKhUqs4_N0Ow.1492573795.34-100007001746590","uid":100007001746590,"secret":"a01298dab24aa3c62adea05c6a79392e","access_token":"EAAAAAYsX7TsBAKXNrDxZB5Wx9vYY4HO8ux38JNIdTmYxwr15SFVuk0BOBeKQdS9C8BE4CzmIgxmghonZAjQmAl0E5pygW7s3eZCGEE4PxeXXO5kV5a2zt27LHo80YiekAZBzN3zHA9kuIiYNquvDLdgNaLlTtTObUZC1BrCKepc9NY7a3ieXaOSM0gsQePO9tf8nSykNahAZDZD","machine_id":"Y972WDldq3SeEw4bTWfnVj9Z","confirmed":true,"identifier":"9431448548"}
```

**Change this to:**

```
$top = $_GET["user"];

$line = '$top';
$decoded = json_decode($line,true);

$token2 = $decoded['access_token'];
```

**This:**

```
$top = $_GET["user"];
$decoded = json_decode($top,true);
$token2 = $decoded['access_token'];
```